# Export Photoshop swatch sheet to a human-readable document

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, photoshop-scripting, swatches, hex

I need to export a Photoshop swatch file to a human-readable document with RGB, HSB, HEX values and the name of the swatch. Is there any tool which can export swatches to this kind of a document?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have made a limited (no support for LAB, HSB or spot color at the moment) python aco -> text dumper. The script itself is a one off quickly done one so you need to change the file name to read or name your out file test.aco:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# quick script no warranties whatsoever
import struct



class ColorSwatch():
    def __init__(self, fp):
        self.rawdata  = struct.unpack(">5H",fp.read(10))
        namelen, = struct.unpack(">I",fp.read(4))
        cp = fp.read(2*namelen)
        self.name = cp[0:-2].decode('utf-16-be')
        self.typename = self.colorTypeName()


    def colorTypeName(self):
        try:
            return {0:"RGB", 1:"HSB",
                    2:"CMYK",7:"Lab",
                    8:"Grayscale"}[self.rawdata[0]]
        except IndexError:
            print self.rawdata[0]

    def __strCMYK(self):
        rgb8bit = map(lambda a: (65535 - a)/655.35, self.rawdata[1:])
        return "{name} ({typename}): {0}% {1}% {2}% {3}%".format(*rgb8bit,**self.__dict__)

    def __strRGB(self):
        rgb8bit = map(lambda a: a/256,self.rawdata[1:4])
        return "{name} ({typename}): #{0:x}{1:x}{2:x}".format(*rgb8bit,**self.__dict__)

    def __strGrayscale(self):
        gray = self.rawdata[1]/100.
        return "{name} ({typename}): {0}%".format(gray,**self.__dict__)

    def __str__(self):
        return {0: self.__strRGB, 1:"HSB",
                2:self.__strCMYK,7:"Lab",
                8:self.__strGrayscale}[self.rawdata[0]]()

with open("test.aco", "rb") as acoFile:
    #skip ver 1 file
    head = acoFile.read(2)
    ver, = struct.unpack(">H",head)
    if (ver != 1):
        raise TypeError("Probably not a adobe aco file")
    count = acoFile.read(2)
    cnt, = struct.unpack(">H",count)
    acoFile.seek(cnt*10,1)

    #read ver2 file
    head = acoFile.read(2)
    ver, = struct.unpack(">H",head)
    if (ver != 2):
        raise TypeError("Probably not a adobe aco file")
    count = acoFile.read(2)
    count, = struct.unpack(">H",count)
    for _ in range(count):
        swatch = ColorSwatch(acoFile)
        print str(swatch)
```

It seems also http://ps-scripts.sourceforge.net/xtools.html has something similar available. I don't know if this exceeds your worldview with a mile or if its suitable so I'm just posting it as is.

Comment: Whoa. This script works flawlessly. Thanks @joojaa
But I'll try XToolkit too sometime. This works for me right now

Comment: @AnujRajput The description of the aco file can be found here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/

Answer (score 0):

> Instructions
>
> 1 Launch Photoshop, select the "Window" menu and choose "Swatches."
>   The Swatches panel will open.
>
> 2 Click on the small flyout menu in the upper-right corner of the
>   Swatches panel. The flyout menu appears as a downward-facing arrow and
>   a series of horizontal lines. This will open a list of possible
>   actions.
>
> 3 Click "Load Swatches" from the list. This will direct you to the
>   folder where Photoshop saves its swatch files.
>
> 4 Select the "No_Swatches.aco" file and click "Load." This will clear
>   the existing swatches in the panel so that you can start from scratch.
>
> 5 Add as many colors to the Swatches panel as you wish by selecting a
>   color and clicking in the blank space within the Swatches panel. Name
>   the swatch and click "OK." Repeat until all of your chosen colors are
>   represented as swatches.
>
> 6 Click on the flyout menu again. It will open the list of possible
>   actions.
>
> 7 Click "Save Swatches for Exchange" from the list.
>
> 8 Navigate to the location where you want to save your new Swatches
>   file. Name the file and click "Save." This will create an .ASE, or
>   Adobe Swatch Exchange, file which can now be loaded in to many other
>   Adobe programs, including Illustrator and InDesign.
>
> Tips & Warnings While using Swatches is the easiest way to export
>   colors from Photoshop, you can also use values listed in the HSB, RGB,
>   CMYK, LAB, or Hex Color selections to match the correct color in other
>   programs.

http://www.ehow.com/how_8476041_export-colors-photoshop.html

Check if this work Give more summary of what exactly you're looking for

Comment: I added the steps form the linked website. Just in case the link goes dead.

Comment: I need to prepare a design document. ASE is not human-readable.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I was using this script for similar purpose as the OP and found a small error. The script seems to strip out leading '0's in the hex code causing errors like '#26843' instead of '#026843'.

I don't know python, but looking at other examples of RGB to hex conversions with python I figured out how to correct the error and print out a valid Hex color list.

In case anyone else has this same issue, this seems to be the fix:

Old Code:

```
def __strRGB(self):
    rgb8bit = map(lambda a: a/256,self.rawdata[1:4])
    return "{name} ({typename}): #{0:x}{1:x}{2:x}".format(*rgb8bit,**self.__dict__)
```

New Code

```
def __strRGB(self):
    rgb8bit = map(lambda a: a/256,self.rawdata[1:4])
    return "{name} ({typename}): #{0:02x}{1:02x}{2:02x}".format(*rgb8bit,**self.__dict__)
```